# Integrate SurveyMonkey in an existing community

Tags: cakephp, surveymonkey

I have a cakePHP community. User are able to signup and login. I like to create a survey using SurveyMonkey. 
Therefor I create the survey and make it available to my members using the direct URL. In my member database I have to save the information "did completed the survey = yes/no".

Is there any way to identify the user filling in the survey and write this information into the database?

Answer (score 2):

SurveyMonkey has an API https://developer.surveymonkey.com/ , that let you collect info from your survey (completedf or not).

This is the only way i think, (if it s not include in your website).

Answer (score 1):

I know that you can simply do this with Examinare Survey Tool. What you do first is that you use the API inside Examinare to add a recipient for all the users in the survey base.

Use the PHP Wrapper library in their developer site.

Loop it through and use the https://developer.examinare.com/php-wrapper-library/  and use the example code.

**If you let people register with same email more than 1 time then save the ContactID into your database on the recipient.**

Then to not create an email invite you use this : markrecipientstosurvey

The surveyID is available inside the Examinare account.

When you done this script part then make it as a cronjob for instance inside the crontab -e

**I would run it every 30 minutes or 1 per hour.**

Next part you create  a page for the survey redirect where you use the function: listsurveysbyuser

to get the survey version and url
 (there is a special link for the mobile user that even works for the normal mobile phone NOT only smartphones)

Now you just redirect them to the survey. If you want them to return to your site after then you use the redirect_url parameter that is added to the url or use the redirect inside your account. Ask support about that if you need :) They are fast... Never had to wait more than a couple of minutes.

When the person return then just check if they are marked as complete with the same api call: listsurveysbyuser

Looks much but it is very easy to implement and if you have any problems then just ask the support at support@examinare.com I have asked alot and never had them to say that it can not be done. Really nice!

EDIT:

I see that they just released a tutorial much better than my example:

https://developer.examinare.com/how-to-use-surveys-in-cakephp-with-very-little-development/

Comment: I just see that Examinare has this blog post.

https://developer.examinare.com/how-to-use-surveys-in-cakephp-with-very-little-development/

Answer (score 0):

One option:

1. Use unique [Custom Variables](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-custom-variables-and-how-do-I-use-them) in the URL that is visited by each member of the community

For example, https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/your_survey?userid=$my_user_id

Note that you can create weblink or email collectors with the API (endpoints: [create_flow](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/create_flow) or [create_collector](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/create_collector)).

2. Then track the responses using the [get_respondent_list](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list) or [get_responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_responses) endpoints of the API.

**Note:** Please confirm with the Survey Monkey API team that the custom variables can be read via the API.

---

Another option:

Use the email collector ([create_flow](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/create_flow)) API endpoint and send it to your members' email addresses.